# Proving that $s$ is a reflexive closure of $r$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, relations

I have this problem that I cannot figure out. Could you please help me out with this?

Let $r$ be a relation on the set $X$ and let $$R:=\{t:t \text{ is a  reflexive relation on } X \text{ with } r\subseteq t \}.$$ For $x,y \in X$ we have $x \, s \, y$ iff for each $t\in R$ we have $x \, t \, y$. Show that $s$ is the reflexive closure of $r$.

My idea so far was as follows.

Suppose $x,y \in X$ and $x \ s \ y$. It follows that for all $t\in R$ we have $x \ t \ y$. Since $r\subseteq t$ for all $t\in R$, it follows $r \subseteq s$ and also $s \subseteq t$. Since each $t\in R$ is reflexive, $s$ is also reflexive.

Could you please verify my idea? I'm sure it has some mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning makes no sense.

Start with an arbitary $x\in X$ and observe that $xtx$ is true for every $t\in R$.

This because every $t\in R$ is reflexive.

Then by definition we have $xsx$.

Proved is now that $s$ is **reflexive**.

---

For proving that $s$ is the **reflexive closure** of $r$ it is enough now to show that $r\subseteq s\subseteq t$ for every $t\in R$.

An interesting fact: the reflexive closure of $r$ is the set $r\cup\Delta$ where $\Delta:=\{\langle x,x\rangle\mid x\in X\}$.

This set $\Delta$ is the so-called diagonal of $X$.

Comment: I don't understand the point "for every $r \in R$". Shouldn't that be "every $t \in R$"?

Comment: @Javiator Slip of the pen. I repaired.

Comment: Could you show me how I can show that $r$ is a subset of $s$?

Comment: If $xry$ then for every $t\in R$ we have $xty$ so that $xsy$ by definition.

Comment: So for the entire proof then would: Suppose $x \in X$. Then by definition of $R$ we have $xtx$ for every $t \in R$. It follows that $xsx$. Hence $s$ is reflexive. 
For proving that $s$ is the reflexive closure of $r$, we show that $r \subseteq s$. Let $xry$ for $x,y \in X$. Then it follows that for every $t \in R$ we have $xty$, from which $xsy$ follows by definition. Hence $r \subseteq s$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Formally you should finish by stating that $s$ is a subset of every $r\in R$. Then you have proved 3 things for $s$: it is reflexive, it contains $r$ and it is contained in every reflexive $t$ that contains $r$. These 3 things are characteristic for reflexive closure of $r$.

Comment: How can I show that $s$ is a subset of every $t \in R$?

Comment: Let $t\in R$ and have a look at the definition of $s$ to observe that $\neg xty\implies\neg xsy$. This is exactly the same statement as $xsy\implies xty$.

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same but how can we say that $\neg xty$? I need to show that $\neg xry \implies \neg xsy$ but for that I need to show $\neg xty$.

Comment: You don't have to show that $\neg xty$. But only that $\neg xty\implies\neg xsy$. The statement "if you go under the shower then you get wet" is simply true. No matter if you go under the shower or not.

Answer (score 1):

The reflexive closure of $r$ is the least relation $r'$ such that whenever $x \, r \, y$  and $x, y \in X$, we have $x \, r' \, x$ and $y \, r' y$ and $x \, r' \, y$. (From this definition, we immediately see that $r'$ is reflexive.)

We first show that $r' \subseteq s$ and then show that $s \subseteq r'$.

Suppose $x \, r' \, y$ and $x,y \in X$.

There are now two cases. If $x = y$, then note that for every reflexive $t$ with $r \subseteq t$ we must have $x \, t \, x$. So $x \, s \, x$. If $x \neq y$, then we again have that $x \, t \, y$ for every reflexive $t$ with $r \subseteq t$. Again, $x \, s \, y$.

Next, suppose $x \, s \, y$. Again, there are two cases. If $x = y$, then by definition, we have $x \, r' \, y$. If $x \neq y$, then for every reflexive $t$ with $r \subseteq t$ we must have $x \, t \, y$. But this then means that $x \, r \, y$.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this has some problems.

> Since $r\subseteq t$ for all $t\in R$, it follows $r \subseteq s$ and also $s \subseteq t$.

How does it follow that $r \subseteq s$? That's not clear.

Fortunately, to show that $s$ is reflexive we don't need it ... yes, we need that $s$ is reflexive, but given its definition that's the *easy* part.

The harder part is that at some point you  need to show that $s$ is the *closure* of $r$, i.e. that $s$ is the *smallest* reflexive relation for which $r \subseteq s$. That part you haven't addressed at all yet.

Comment: Is the rest except the part you mentioned correct? Just to be sure about my reasoning.

Comment: @Javiator Well, there really isn't much more to your argument ... If you mean is your *setup* ok .. well, that's a little weird too. If you want to show reflexivity, you have to show $x \  s \ x$ for any $x$, so you wouldn't start with $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll correct that. For the harder part: Can I say that since for $x,y \in X$ and $xry$ it follows that $xty$ for every $t \in R$, because by definition $r \subseteq t$, and thus $xsy$ and $r \subseteq s$?

Comment: No, that last part does not follow.  You have for any $t$ that $r \subseteq t$ and $s \subseteq t$, but from that you can't get $r \subseteq s$.  Here's what I would do: being the reflexive closure of $r$, $s$ is adding to $r$ any $<x,x>$ that weren't already in $r$ (again, that just means $s$ is reflexive), but $s$ is not adding other new pairs to $r$. In other words, you need to show that for any $x$ and $y$ with $x \not = y$: if $<x,y> \in r$, then $<x,y> \in s$ (it doesn't remove any existing ones from $r$ either) and if $<x,y> \not \in r$, then $<x,y> \not \in s$

Comment: But with my comment I do show that every $<x,y> \in r$ is also $<x,y> \in s$ right? But not if $<x,y> \not \in r$ is also $<x,y> \not \in s$?